# How to replace date picker in ckan?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker, ckan

I’m currently working with ckan 2.10 and also I install ckanext-scheming extension. When we add a metadata field with date preset, it shows a date picker which is not a part of scheming extension and it is set by the ckan itself. I need to change this date picker to another one. How can I do that and where should I look?